# Select value from database and store into a temporary variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select a stored value from database and then put it into a temporary variable.

For example, I have a column called `category`, one value under it is `m`, so I want to select this `m` value from the database, let's say from a table of a database called `user_info`.

Then I want to put it into a variable, let's name it `$res`.

After that, I want to do some condition stuff, such as `if $res=="m"`,

Can anyone help me write a simple structure here?

Here is the code:

```
<?php   
$sql = "Select category FROM user_info WHERE user_name = '"
       .$_SESSION['username']."' and password = '".$_SESSION['password']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if($res == "a"){
  include('MPIncomeStrategy.php');
}

if($res == "b"){
  include('MPIncomeStrategy.php');
}
```

But it seems that the code is not able to detect `$res =="category value in database"`. Did I just use the wrong way to store the category value?

Comment: Please show some code, and take the time to format your question in such a way that we have some idea what you're talking about.

Comment: `$res` is a result resource and you need to fetch a row from it. It contains no data itself.  `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);  echo $row['category'];`

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so so so much man

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Secondly, take a look at the documentation for using `mysql_*` functions. In your code, `$res` is a resource, not an array of values. In order to extract the data from `$res` you have to call `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, both of which will return an array (`mysql_fetch_array()` returns a combination of numbered indexes and associative indexes; `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns only an associative array).

Once you have the array, you may access the indexes.

Like this:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if /* or while */ ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $category = $row['category'];

    if ($category == "m") { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will organize my code according to your advice. Thank you so much